# Is it possible to send data using vbscript from client to server without any freeware downloads?

Tags: networking, tcp, vbscript, automation

For example is it possible using base windows 10 to create a vbscript server and client using tcp to send the string "hello world" from client to server?

How can I do this using base windows 10?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, of course, it is possible.
Via vbscript, no; But, you can always send via vbscript a command line with the right settings, and that's it.

But, be careful, VBScript is 20 years old!
Better is Python, PS, ... etc.

Here is a link where a vbscript client sends a request to an http server.

[How to call web service using vbscript (synchronous)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545790/how-to-call-web-service-using-vbscript-synchronous)